# Can corrective lenses be used to change the horizontal and vertical sizes of the images perceived by the eyes?

Tags: optometry

Given a condition in which each eye percieves the same image as slightly larger or smaller than the other in the horizonal or vertical direction - thus making it more difficult to combine the two into a single coherent image - can corrective lenses be used to adjust the images so that they both appear the same size?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Is this purely hypothetical, or do you believe that this condition actually occurs? On physical grounds, this doesn't seem possible. The size of the image on the retina is given by the product DA, where D is the diameter of the eyeball and A is the angular size of the object in radians. (This assumes that it's in focus on the retina. If it's not in focus, you would presumably wear glasses to correct for that.) Even if the size of the image were somehow wrong (e.g., if the eyeball changed size), your eye-brain system is probably plastic enough to adapt over time.